# is there any UI component for arranging elements as grid with WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I created a view model with an ObservableCollection(of strings) property.
I want to create a view(XAML) which arranges the collection items as a grid.

for example, if my collection contains Kim,Ron,Peter,Nick,Tom,Dan,Bella,Rose...

It will be arranges like this:

Kim  Ron  Peter

Nick  Tom  Dan

Bella  Rose  ...

Is there any UI component which can use my collection as itemsSource and arranges it as I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use any UIElement that derives from `ItemsControl`, such as `ListBox`, and change its `ItemsPanel` to be a `UniformGrid` with a `Columns` size of 3.

For example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: *that derives from ItemsControl* - or just ItemsControl, if you don't need support for selecting items.

Comment: @Clemens, you are correct.  That is a noteworthy clarification.